# WCF web service, Entity Framework and keeping SQL sessions alive (slow first start!)

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, iis-7, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF web service hosted on IIS 7. This web service serves up JSON content for use in mobile apps. It uses the Entity Framework on top of MS SQL 2005, and the Interface contract looks like the below:

```
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface MyService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetStuff?skip={skip}&take={take}&loanAmt={loanAmt}&propertyVal={propertyVal}&Term={Term}&MonthlyRent={MonthlyRent}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        ProductsDTO GetProducts(int skip, int take, decimal loanAmt, decimal propertyVal, int Term, decimal MonthlyRent);
    }
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
    public ProductsDTO GetProducts(int skip, int take, decimal loanAmt, decimal propertyVal, int Term, decimal MonthlyRent)
    {
       //Some set up code
      using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities()) 
        {
              //Get our products
        }

     return ReturnedList
    }
```

On the first run of this, it can take anywhere up to 15 seconds (unacceptable for a mobile app), on subsequent runs, the data comes back in under a second. After 5 minutes of inactivity, the WCF service reverts to taking 15 seconds to start.

I initially thought the bottle neck was at IIS7 and thought my App Pool was shutting off. After setting the App Pool to never recycle and studying w3wp.exe processes on the IIS server, I realized this was not the case. It is the database session that is shutting off after those five minutes.

This being the case, I want to hold a SQL session open to immediately serve up requests from the WCF application, however, I don't want to set the Entity Context as a singleton or leave this open in the service as I understand this is poor practise. I could pass a SQL connection object TO the context (using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities(MySQLConnection))) and hold that open? Or can someone suggest something else?

I had seen lots of posts with scripts that touch the web service to keep it alive which gave me the creeping horrors, so have avoided going down this route.

What are your thoughts?

**Update 1**

As per Andomars response, I have added the following initialization code to the WCF service.

```
   public Service1()
        {
            // Blocking call that initializes
            // the service instance
            this.Initialize();
        }

        BackgroundWorker KeepSQLAlive = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void Initialize()
        {
            KeepSQLAlive.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(KeepSQLAlive_DoWork);

            KeepSQLAlive.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void KeepSQLAlive_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Timer pingback = new Timer(180000);

            pingback.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(pingback_Elapsed);

            pingback.Start();
        }

        void pingback_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities ())
            {
                context.ExecuteStoreCommand("select @@servername");
            }
        }
```

This feels like a bit of a fudge, and I'm a bit worried without creating the service as a singleton the service will continue to spawn SQL sessions without ever killing any. However, if it works it is the path of least resistance as hosting this code in a windows service would take more time and I am unclear how to integrate this in with IIS security (I want to use SSL). I will report back whether the above works. (thanks for the assistance all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a background thread that runs `select @@servername` (or another trivial query) every minute.  That should keep the connection pool warm.

Comment: I have added initilization code to the service to start a background process off to do the above (see the edit!)... it appears to be working... I will keep an eye on the SQL activity monitor to see if this is performant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Web service shouldnt run background threads so..
2. Write Windows Service with WCF contract as a proxy between IIS and Database.
3. Make sure you are using connection pooling on your Windows Service.
4. Query something from DB every 30 seconds/ 1 minute / 5 minutes (this time have to be tested) from your windows service. After query remember to close your connection (this will not close real connection but will make connection available for the pool). This will keep at least one active connection in pool ready for your request.
5. Use pipes (NetNamedPipeBinding) between WCF service on IIS and Windows Service (it's fast).
6. Think about publishing already compiled application on your IIS. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx)

Comment: This looks like the proper way to achieve my goals, however, as I am using "web deploy" which gives me a beautiful one click deployment, and I want to use IIS security, I think this method will be more work to get no better result. Please correct me if I am wrong, and thanks for the help besides.